# Instagram Widget is not loading properly in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, ios12

I'm facing an issue with Instagram Widget. I'm loading HTML content in WKWebView. But thumbnail is not loading in below iOS 13.0 version. Any solution?

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you share the html content to reproduce the issue?

Comment: added in the question

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with referencing the `embed.js` file in the html code.

instead of this,

```
<script async src="//www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>
```

Replace with,

```
<script async src="https://www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>
```

We can also keep the  `embed.js` file in the xcode project and compile it  .

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0Mxw.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsSMx.png)

For reference , I have committed project in Github : https://github.com/vinayakasy99/InstaWebview

Comment: Thank you for your solution but I can't keep embed.js in local. Because it should be dispatch at runtime from Instagram. 

Do you any specific solution?

Comment: yes, try - >  src="https://www.instagram.com/embed.js". It worked for me.

Comment: What is the issue ? Try different instagram post or this project , https://github.com/vinayakasy99/InstagramStory

Comment: @VinayakaSY If I replace with  src="https://platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js"  then also it is working. is this correct?
<script async defer src="https://platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js"></script>